# django templates syntax mixed with javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, templates

My js code is in the .html django template inside a block, this way:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
... some blocks here ...
{% block javascript %}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    ...
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Now I need to use in the js code some context vars passed from the view to the template. I used a option where I declared in an html element a data attr using django template syntax {{ ... }}

```
<div id="order_id" data-order-id={{order.id}}>
```

and with jq I got this element and read the data value. This way:

```
var orderId = $("#order_id").data('order-id')
```

this works fairly well, but I realized if I have the code in the same .html I can use the django template expressions as part of my js code. This way:

```
var orderId = {{ order.id }};
var changeStatusUrl = "{% url 'orders:change_status' %}"
```

This works fairly well too, so my question is if this is a good practice to follow with, or if this has some drawback that I will face in the future.

Comment: Not {%estends%} but extends...

Comment: might be a problem when you need to separate out JS code from your HTML in future. Recommended way is to keep JS and HTML separate.

Answer (score 0):

If the proyect is medium sized. What I normally implement is to have a separate JavaScript file. Before the import of the file I generate the needed variables from Django template expresions.

For instance if drawing a line graph. My variable data would have the needed values. Then I would import a script that buids in top of the variable.

```
<script>var data = [{% for s in stats %}{{s}},{% endfor %}];</script>
<script src="{% static "myapp/js/line.js" %}"></script>
```